# SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Firefox keeps giving me this message:

```
 Hour: 16:11:32
 Erro: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 Line: 12, Column: 2

 Messages: { name: { required: "Your name here", minlength:
```

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        alert("Hello evrbdy");
    });

    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $("a").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#fomu").validate({
        rules: {
            nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }
        }
        messages: {
            nome: {
                required: "some message",
                minlength: "some other message"
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you're missing a `}`

Comment: You're missing a comma between rules and messages in the options for validate.

Comment: Proper indentation would help...

Comment: Please, avoid using stackoverflow to debug your code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
rules:{ 
    nome:{
        required: true, 
        minlength: 6
    } 
},
messages:{  
    nome:{  
        required: "some message",   
        minlength: "some other message"
    }
```

Missing comma after rules data object

Answer (score 6):

Run your code through [a beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to fix the spacing and it would be easier to spot:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        alert("Hello evrbdy");
    });

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("a").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#fomu").validate({
        rules: {
            nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }
        }, // <-- missing comma here
        messages: {
            nome: {
                required: "some message",
                minlength: "some other message"
            }
        }
    });
});
```