# ReactJS with Fetch on older browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, fetch-api

I am implementing React JS, with Webpack and Babel. However, I am having trouble getting Fetch to work with IE 11.

I have the following in my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets" : ["env", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

and the following in my webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      SRC_DIR + '/app/index.js',
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + '/public/js',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

From my understanding implementing babel-preset-env, stage-0, and babel-polyfill should have allowed for the Fetch API to be transpiled into something older browsers could understand. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Just wanted to add this for future reference in case people are surprised that IE 11 doesn't support fetch: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch

Answer (score 2):

`fetch` isn't part of EcmaScript but its part of the **web platform**. Babel is only a **compiler** to write the latest Javascript. If you want to use `fetch` in older browsers you need a polyfill like [this one](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Fetch API: [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` must be made available by the browser you use and is not included in `babel-polyfill`. If your browser doesn't support `fetch`, you can either fall back to using `XMLHttpRequest` or use a polyfill such as [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch).